# Update array object based on id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having a bit of a mongo issue. I was wondering if there was a way to do the following in a mongo console command rather then multiple `find` and `update` calls.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b429ba0e27b508d854483e"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "letter" : "b"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
```

I want to update the object with this new array item

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "letter": "c"
}
```

I used this, `addToSet` is limited, it won't insert an item into the array if it is already there but it will not update an item based on an identifier. In this case I would really like to update this entry based on the `id`.

```
db.soup.update({
     "tester": "tom"
 }, {
     $addToSet: {
         "array": {
             "id": "2",
             "letter": "c"
         }
     }
});
```

This gives me:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b429ba0e27b508d854483e"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "letter" : "b"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "letter" : "c"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
```

When what I really wanted was:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b429ba0e27b508d854483e"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "letter" : "c"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) positional operator to do this:

```js
db.soup.update(
    {_id: ObjectId("50b429ba0e27b508d854483e"), 'array.id': '2'}, 
    {$set: {'array.$.letter': 'c'}})
```

The `$` in the update object acts as a placeholder for the first element of `array` to match the query selector.

Comment: This is great. I just realized that this is what I have. The more complicated question is now, how do I also get it to push a new object eg `{"id":3,"letter":"d"}` in a sort of upsert kind of way into the array? Do I have to programmatically sort the requests out? If it exists use `$set` if not `$push`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi It would be better if you asked that as a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588342/can-mongo-handle-this-or-do-i-have-to-do-this-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
> db.collection.insert( { array : [ { id : 1, letter : 'a' }, { id : 2, letter : 'b' } ], tester : 'tom' } );
> db.collection.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b431a69a0358d590a2f5f0"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "letter" : "b"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
> db.collection.update( { tester : 'tom' }, { $set : { 'array.1' : { id : 2, letter : 'c' } } }, false, true );
> db.collection.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b431a69a0358d590a2f5f0"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "letter" : "c"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
```

The trick lies in the false, true, false.
That is: true for upsert, false for update multiple.

For more details check out:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29

Comment: You are updating based on the array position (`array.1`) rather than finding the entry where `id` is `2`.  This only works if you already know the position of the element in the array, rather than just the `id`.

Comment: The question implied that the criterion was { tester : 'tom' } and that he wanted to replace the second element of the 'array' list. If the criterion must also include { 'array.id' : 2 } then JohnnyHK's solution looks like the winner here.