# Can mongo upsert array data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo document like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b429ba0e27b508d854483e"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "letter" : "b"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
```

I want to be able to insert and update the `array` with a single mongo command and not use a conditional within a `find()` then run `insert()` and `update()` depending on the presence of the object.

The `id` is the item I want to be the selector. So if I update the array with this:

```
{
    "id" : "2",
    "letter" : "c"
}
```

I have to use a `$set` statement

```
db.soup.update({
    "tester":"tom",
    'array.id': '2'
}, {
    $set: {
        'array.$.letter': 'c'
    }
})
```

And if I want to insert a new object into the array

```
{
    "id" : "3",
    "letter" : "d"
}
```

I have to use a `$push` statement

```
db.soup.update({
    "tester":"tom"
}, {
    $push: {
        'array': {
            "id": "3",
            "letter": "d"
        }
    }
})
```

I need a sort of upsert for an array item.

Do I have to do this programmatically or can I do this with a single mongo call?

Comment: It amazes me that mongo still doesn't have this basic functionality that I run into multiple times in every project I've used mongo with :/

Comment: In 2022, Mongo does have some options with aggregate pipeline updates. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array/65967584#65967584 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array/72434562#72434562. Both are rather verbose but get the job done.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not aware of an option that would upsert into an embedded array as at MongoDB 2.2, so you will likely have to handle this in your application code.

Given that you want to treat the embedded array as sort of a virtual collection, you may want to consider modelling the array as a separate collection instead.

You can't do an upsert based on a field value within an embedded array, but you could use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) to insert an embedded document if it doesn't exist already:

```
db.soup.update({
    "tester":"tom"
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        'array': {
            "id": "3",
            "letter": "d"
        }
    }
})
```

That doesn't fit your exact use case of matching by `id` of the array element, but may be useful if you know the expected current value.

Comment: Note that some form of "virtual collection" support for embedded documents is a popular request .. you can vote/watch [SERVER-142](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

Answer (score 25):

I just ran into this problem myself. I wasn't able to find a one-call solution, but I found a two-call solution that works *when you have a unique value in your array elements*. Use the `$pull` command first, which removes elements from an array, and then `$push`.

```
db.soup.update({
    "tester":"tom"
}, {
    $pull: {
        'array': {
            "id": "3"
        }
    }
})
db.soup.update({
    "tester":"tom"
}, {
    $push: {
        'array': {
            "id": "3",
            "letter": "d"
        }
    }
})
```

This should work when the document doesn't exist, when the document exists but the entry in the array doesn't exist, and when the entry exists.

Again, this only works if you have something, like the `id` field in this example, that should be unique across elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks, it works well when searching using 2 fields in document

Comment: Add a `$exists` check in `$push` query, so that it fails if something happens between the 2 calls.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this problem as well - some years later. Is there any updates to this?

Comment: @DauleDK a quick search turned this up: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/

Comment: Do you think bulk-find-upsert can solve this problem in one query?

Comment: This is a cool solution, but it has a drawback though. It changes the order of items in the array whenever there is an update. The updated item always goes to the end of the array, which is undesirable if the order of items is important.

Comment: Is this not possible even now? i.e. in a single call.

Comment: @SubhamSaha looking at the docs I still don't see a way to do it in one call (and this question still getting traffic after 8 years also suggests that), but it looks like there may be better ways to do it in two calls now. It's probably worth updating my answer to include the new info.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve upserts of embedded document sets in some cases if you can restructure your documents to use objects instead of arrays. I just answered this on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871363/upsert-array-elements-matching-criteria-in-a-mongodb-document/21347039#21347039) but will adapt it here for convenience.

---

An example document would be

```
{
    tester: 'tom',
    items: {
        '1': 'a',
        '2': 'b'
    }
}
```

To upsert an item with `id` 3 and value 'c', you'd do

```
db.coll.update(
    { tester: 'tom' }, 
    { $set: { 'items.3': 'c' } }
)
```

One drawback is that querying for field names (using the `$exists` query operator) requires scanning. You can get around this by adding an extra array field that stores the property names. This field can be indexed and queried normally. Upserts become

```
db.coll.update(
    { tester: 'tom' }, 
    { 
        $set: { 'items.3': 'c' },
        $addToSet: { itemNames: 3 }
    }
)
```

(Keep in mind `$addToSet` is O(n).) When removing a property, you have to pull it from the array as well.

```
db.widgets.update(
    { tester: 'tom' }, 
    { 
        $unset: { 'items.3': true },
        $pull: { itemNames: 3 }
    }
)
```

Comment: This works, but beware that you will lose the ability to index the items by ID, since mongo doesn't have a way to create an index on all keys of a given sub-object.

Answer (score 2):

The question is from 2012. I had a look into the mongo documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert which Rob Watts mentioned in a comment, but it is very sparse.

I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952359/1374488

Answer (score 2):

With [mongo 4.2 adding support for aggregation pipelines in update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) I was able to use [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/), [$concatArrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/), [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/), and [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to pull this together in a single call.

```
db.soup.updateOne(
  { tester: 'tom' },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        array: {
          $concatArrays: [
            [{ id: '2', letter: 'c' }],
            {
              $ifNull: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: '$array',
                    as: 'item',
                    cond: {
                      $ne: [
                        '$$item.id',
                        '2',
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
                [],
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
)
```

This will replace the item where `id` is `'2'`, if no other items in the array match, it will append the item.

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can do by using array filters option.
You can refer here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-arrayfilters.

```
   db.getCollection('soup').update({'tester':tom}, { $set: { "collection.$[element].letter" : 'c' } },
   {
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.id": 2 } ]
   })
```

Comment: This would be very useful, but in my hands it only works if the identifiers are the same in the update object and the array filter, e.g.:    `db.collection.update({'tester': 'tom'}, { $set: { "array.$[element].letter": "c"}}, { arrayFilters: [ { "element.letter": "b"} ]})` - which is much less helpful.  Also, the `upsert` option mentioned in the docs allows you to insert a new document if one is not matched, and not add a new element to the array, so this doesn't solve the OPs problem.