# Upsert a subdocument using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can mongo upsert data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588342/can-mongo-upsert-data)

I have schemas defined as follows:

```
var Permission = new Schema({
  _id: String,  // email address
  role: String  // "admin" or "member"
});

var Org = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}, trim: true},
  permissions: [Permission]
});
```

I am trying to either match and update a subdocument row (in my case, 'permissions', or insert a new permissins row if no match (e.g. upsert).

Here is what I have written:

```
exports.updatePermissions = function(req, res) {
  return Org
    .update(
      {name:"my_org", "permissions.$._id": req.body.email},
      {$set: {"permissions.$.role": req.body.role}})
    .exec(function(err) {
      // stuff
    });
};
```

MongoDB seems to accept this (e.g. no errors), but there is no change in the DB.  I tried the following in the mongo shell as well:

```
db.orgs.update({"name":"my_org", "permissions.$._id":"newuser@email.com"}, {$set: {"permissions.$.role": "member"}});
```

Again, Mongo accepted the query, but no change.  Here is the document that I am trying to modify:

```
{
    "name" : "my_org",
    "permissions" : [
        {
            "_id" : "newuser@email.com",
            "role" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions?  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/), also check out the [rules for the $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_):

```
db.orgs.update({"name":"my_org", "permissions": {$elemMatch: {_id:"newuser@email.com"}}},
     {$set: {"permissions.$.role": "member"}});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works for me to update an existing entry, but it does not insert a non-existant entry (I added upsert=true as well).  Do you have advice on how the upsert would work here?

Comment: I think your out of luck on the upsert. The "$" operator doc specifically warns against using it for "upsert" operations.