# Json.net: Merge two json arrays by objects Id

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to upset a json array by objects id, for example. let's say I have this json array:

```
 [{"Id":"1", "a":"1", "b":"2"},
  {"Id":"2", "a":"3", "b":"1"},
  {"Id":"3", "a":"5", "b":"1"}]
```

And I would like to Upsert it with this array

```
 [{"Id":"1", "a":"32", "b":"42"},
 {"Id":"2", "a":"3", "b":"1", "c":"23"},
  {"Id":"12", "a":"12", "b":"45"}]
```

The expected result should be:

```
[{"Id":"1", "a":"32", "b":"42"},
  {"Id":"2", "a":"3", "b":"1", "c":"23"},
  {"Id":"3", "a":"5", "b":"1"},
  {"Id":"12", "a":"12", "b":"45"}]
```

Comment: Where does MongoDB fit in the picture?

Comment: And while we're at it, where'd the c=23 property of object 2 come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588342/can-mongo-upsert-array-data

Comment: H W, thanks, but this does not answer my question, it's similar, but i need the ability to **upsert** and not update or insert

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/wiki/MergeSample

Comment: Md. Parvez Alam, this does not solve the problem. I need to merge arrays using the elements ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be easily done in C#. If you map your entities to something like that:

```
[DataContract]
public class Entity
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "a")]
    public int? A { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "b")]
    public int? B { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "c")]
    public int? C { get; set; }
}
```

I think it's not possible to perform desired action using LINQ, but good old foreach will solve your issue.

**EDIT:** Actually after looking at @vadim-gremyachev answer I think it can be done with LINQ very well:

```
var l1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Entity>>(
    @"[{""Id"":""1"", ""a"":""1"", ""b"":""2""}, 
       {""Id"":""2"", ""a"":""3"", ""b"":""1""}, 
       {""Id"":""3"", ""a"":""5"", ""b"":""1""}]");

var l2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Entity>>(
    @"[{""Id"":""1"", ""a"":""32"", ""b"":""42""},
       {""Id"":""2"", ""a"":""3"", ""b"":""1"", ""c"":""23""},
       {""Id"":""12"", ""a"":""12"", ""b"":""45""}]");

// LINQ
var res = l1.Concat(l2).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.Last()).ToList();

// Foraech
var res2 = new List<Entity>(l1);
foreach (var l2Entity in l2)
{
    var resEntity = res2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == l2Entity.Id);
    if (resEntity == null)
    {
        res2.Add(l2Entity);
    }
    else
    {
        res2[res2.IndexOf(resEntity)] = l2Entity;
    }
}
```

Then you can just serialize your `res` list back to JSON and it's done:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```

The resulting JSON will be:

```
[
    {"Id":"1","a":32,"b":42},
    {"Id":"2","a":3,"b":1,"c":23},
    {"Id":"3","a":5,"b":1},
    {"Id":"12","a":12,"b":45}
]
```

You can also use `l1` and do not create `res`, it's depending on your case of course. You might also want to order the resulting collection by key after merge is done.

Comment: You don't really need an entity to do what's asked, but it could be a good idea nonetheless because I guess there are other manipulations the OP could want to do on the entities, so it's nice to have a strongly typed object. What's really useless though are the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes. You can survive with your entities having some lowercase properties.

Comment: In provided JSON there is a strange naming, when `Id` starts with capital letter and other properties not. In such cases `Data` attributes might be a good choice if you want resulting JSON to follow the same rules.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use Linq on your `JArray`, as these are `IEnumerable<JToken>`

```
var first = JArray.Parse(@"[{'Id':'1', 'a':'1', 'b':'2'},
            {'Id':'2', 'a':'3', 'b':'1'},
            {'Id':'3', 'a':'5', 'b':'1'}]");


var second = JArray.Parse(@"[{'Id':'1', 'a':'32', 'b':'42'},
            {'Id':'2', 'a':'3', 'b':'1', 'c':'23'},
            {'Id':'12', 'a':'12', 'b':'45'}]");

var resultAsEnumerable = first.Concat(second)
                              .GroupBy(t => t["Id"])
                              .Select(g => g.Last());
```

If you need your result as a `JArray`, you can easily convert the result to it:

```
var resultAsJArray = new JArray(resultAsEnumerable.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = JArray.Parse(@"[{'Id':'1', 'a':'1', 'b':'2'},
                        {'Id':'2', 'a':'3', 'b':'1'},
                        {'Id':'3', 'a':'5', 'b':'1'}]");


var y = JArray.Parse(@"[{'Id':'1', 'a':'32', 'b':'42'},
                        {'Id':'2', 'a':'3', 'b':'1', 'c':'23'},
                        {'Id':'12', 'a':'12', 'b':'45'}]");

//1. Union arrays skipping items that already exist
x.Merge(y, new JsonMergeSettings
        {
            MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union,
        });

//2. Get distinct items by key (Id) 
var result = x.GroupBy(i => i["Id"]).Select(g => g.Last()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few of these answers and they only partly worked for me, ordering the result json is left for a exercise for the reader, you probably would want the input json to not have ID as string for this to work properly. Tested using .net core 3.1.

```
var input1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(@"[  {'Id':'1', 'a':'1', 'b':'2'},
                                                        { 'Id':'2', 'a':'3', 'b':'1'},
                                                        { 'Id':'3', 'a':'5', 'b':'1'}]");

var input2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(@" [  {'Id':'1', 'a':'32', 'b':'42'},
                                                         {'Id':'2', 'a':'3', 'b':'1', 'c':'23'},
                                                         {'Id':'12', 'a':'12', 'b':'45'}]");

//you may want this the other way depending on what your trying to do
//input1.Merge(input2);
input2.Merge(input1);

var res = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (var x in input2.GroupBy(x => x["Id"]).ToList())
{
      var newItem = new ExpandoObject();
      foreach (var y in x)
      {
            foreach (JProperty z in y)
            {
                 newItem.TryAdd(z.Name, z.Value);
            }
       }
       res.Add(newItem);

 }

 Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
[{
        "Id": "1",
        "a": "32",
        "b": "42"
    }, {
        "Id": "2",
        "a": "3",
        "b": "1",
        "c": "23"
    }, {
        "Id": "12",
        "a": "12",
        "b": "45"
    }, {
        "Id": "3",
        "a": "5",
        "b": "1"
    }
]
```