# MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
    "myarray" : [ 
        {
            userId : ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
            point : 5
        },
        {
            userId : ObjectId("613ca5e48dbe673802c2d521"),
            point : 2
        },        
     ]
}
```

#### These are my questions

I want to push into `myarray` if `userId` doesn't exist, it should be appended to `myarray`. If `userId` exists, it should be updated to point.

#### I found this

```
db.collection.update({
    _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
    "myarray.userId" :  ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")
}, {
    $set: { "myarray.$.point": 10 }
})
```

But if `userId` doesn't exist, nothing happens.

#### and

```
db.collection.update({
    _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")
}, {
  $push: {
      "myarray": {
          userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
          point: 10
      }
  }
})
```

But if `userId` object already exists, it will push again.

What is the best way to do this in MongoDB?

Comment: For reference, I added my verbose solution to the answer at the following link that covers the same scenario, ie `how to add a new object to an array of objects unless a specific object value (eg userId) exists, in which case update the object`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671119

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this

```
db.collection.update(
    { _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
    { $pull: {"myarray.userId": ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")}}
)
db.collection.update(
    { _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
    { $push: {"myarray": {
        userId:ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
        point: 10
    }}
)
```

Explination: 
in the first statment `$pull` removes the element with `userId= ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")` from the array on the document where `_id =  ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")`

In the second one `$push` inserts 
this object `{ userId:ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"), point: 10 }` in the same array.

Comment: would be great to explicit what your code does for future readers

Comment: ok , that is greate but in MongoDb the id should inserted automatically whereas you added it manually

Comment: two different cals, a great ideea but expensive.

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer by Flying Fisher is that the existing record will first be deleted, and then it will be pushed again.

A safer approach (common sense) would be to try to update the record first, and if that did not find a match, insert it, like so:

```
// first try to overwrite existing value
var result = db.collection.update(
   {
       _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
       "myarray.userId": ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")
   },
   {
       $set: {"myarray.$.point": {point: 10}}
   }
);
// you probably need to modify the following if-statement to some async callback
// checking depending on your server-side code and mongodb-driver
if(!result.nMatched)
{
    // record not found, so create a new entry
    // this can be done using $addToSet:
    db.collection.update(
        {
            _id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")
        },
        {
            $addToSet: {
                myarray: {
                    userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                    point: 10
                }
            }
        }
    );
    // OR (the equivalent) using $push:
    db.collection.update(
        {
            _id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
            "myarray.userId": {$ne: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"}}
        },
        {
            $push: {
                myarray: {
                    userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                    point: 10
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This should also give (common sense, untested) an increase in performance, if in most cases the record already exists, only the first query will be executed.

Comment: What happens if two concurrent requests enter simultaneously into the if-statements? only one of two 
`$addToSet` has effect, hasn't it?

Comment: @FabioFormosa Yeah, but you're right, this is still unsafe. What if meanwhile, not only `$addToSet` is executed, but also the points are updated... This code should definitely be in a transaction.

Answer (score 21):

There is a option called [update documents with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from **MongoDB v4.2**,

- check condition `$cond` if `userId` in `myarray.userId` or not
- if yes then `$map` to iterate loop of `myarray` array and check condition if `userId` match then merge with new document using `$mergeObjects`
- if no then `$concatArrays` to concat new object and `myarray`

```
let _id = ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408");
let updateDoc = {
  userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
  point: 10
};

db.collection.update(
  { _id: _id },
  [{
    $set: {
      myarray: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [updateDoc.userId, "$myarray.userId"] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$myarray",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.userId", updateDoc.userId] },
                      updateDoc,
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          { $concatArrays: ["$myarray", [updateDoc]] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pd4YRqwdo3S)

Comment: That's a great way to solve that. I tried to "improve" it by first setting the index of the element to be updated and using that avoid going through the array multiple times. But I can't figure out how to use that index to only update the right element like [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tFTjOIg0jLh). So I'll go with your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately "upsert" operation is not possible on embedded array. Operators simply do not exist so that this is not possible in a single statement.Hence you must perform two update operations in order to do what you want. Also the order of application for these two updates is important to get desired result.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any solutions based on a one atomic query. Instead there are 3 ways based on a sequence of two queries:

1. always `$pull` (to remove the item from array), then `$push` (to add the updated item to array)

   ```
   db.collection.update(
                  { _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
                  { $pull: {"myarray.userId": ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")}}
   )

   db.collection.update(
                  { _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
                  {
                    $push: {
                             "myarray": {
                                         userId:ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                                         point: 10
                                        }
                            }
                   }
   )
   ```
2. try to `$set` (to update the item in array if exists), then get the result and check if the updating operation successed or if a `$push` needs (to insert the item)

   ```
   var result = db.collection.update(
       {
          _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
         "myarray.userId": ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")
       },
       {
          $set: {"myarray.$.point": {point: 10}}
       }
    );

   if(!result.nMatched){
          db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
                               {
                                 $addToSet: {
                                              myarray: {
                                                 userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                                                 point: 10
                                             }
                               }
          );
   ```
3. always `$addToSet` (to add the item if not exists), then always `$set` to update the item in array

   ```
      db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
                            myarray: { $not: { $elemMatch: {userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")} } } },
                           { 
                              $addToSet : {
                                            myarray: {
                                                       userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                                                       point: 10
                                                      }
                                           }
                            },
                           { multi: false, upsert: false});

      db.collection.update({
                             _id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
                              "myArray.userId": ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")
                           },
                           { $set : { myArray.$.point: 10 } },
                           { multi: false, upsert: false});
   ```

1st and 2nd way are **unsafe**, so transaction must be established to avoid two concurrent requests could `push` the same item generating a duplicate.

3rd way is safer. the `$addToSet` adds only if the item doesn't exist, otherwise nothing happens. In case of two concurrent requests, only one of them adds the missing item to the array.

Comment: How is approach #3 safe? If a concurrent request has modified the array element so that `points` is no longer `10` then the first call will add a second element for the same `userId` to the array.

Comment: The only race condition would be: the element is not in the array, the first request completes the `$addToSet`, now the second request runs both `updates` and finally the first request runs the `$set`. There will be always one only element (never two!) because only one `$addToSet` hits! The value of the point field will be the value of the last request that executes the `$set`. You shouldn't interested to which request executes the `$addToSet `. So it's a safer way because it doesn't fall in a double insert.

Comment: If an array element exists for the same `userId` but with a different `point` value, then a second element for the same `userId` would be added to the array. The `$addToSet` approach would only work if `10` is forever the only possible value for `point` which is unlikely.

Comment: No, if it exists an array element for the same `userId` the `$addToSet` of the first `update` will have no effect.

Comment: `$addToSet` only compares entire array elements. `{ userId: 1, point: 2 }` and `{ userId: 1, point: 4 }` are *different* elements and thus `$addToSet` will add both entries. `$addToSet` cannot know that `userId` has some special index-like meaning.

Comment: Sure, but take a look to the selection clause in the `update` statement (`$not $elemMatch` on userId) and the `upsert=false`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. I have missed the `$elemMatch` because I didn't scroll far enough. In that case you're right - it should work. You can even use `$push` instead of `$addToSet` because you've basically covered the set behavior by the `$elemMatch` filter.

Comment: I've just re-edited that line to avoid the horinzontal scroll that caused the misunderstanding. It could be useful to other people. Thank you a lot for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.update(
      { _id },
      [
        {
          $set: {
            myarray: { $filter: {
              input: '$myarray',
              as: 'myarray',
              cond: { $ne: ['$$myarray.userId', ObjectId('570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035')] },
            } },
          },
        },
        {
          $set: {
            myarray: {
              $concatArrays: [
                '$myarray',
                [{ userId: ObjectId('570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035'), point: 10 },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    );
```

We use 2 stages:

1. filter `myarray` (= remove element if `userId` exist)
2. concat filtered `myarray` with new element;

Answer (score 0):

When you want update or insert value in array try it

Object in db

```
key:name,
key1:name1,
arr:[
    {
        val:1,
        val2:1
    }
]
```

Query

```
var query = {
    $inc:{
        "arr.0.val": 2,
        "arr.0.val2": 2
    }
}
.updateOne( { "key": name }, query, { upsert: true }

key:name,
key1:name1,
arr:[
    {
        val:3,
        val2:3
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB 3.6 it is now possible to [upsert elements in an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#upsert).

Comment: Unfortunately, the upsert option doesn't really help solve this problem, because it requires an [exact equality match for the array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#array-match-exact) (i.e. all array elements are explicitly defined in the query).  If a match is not found then upsert will create an entire new document, but it will not 'upsert' a new element into an array.

Answer (score -1):

array update and create don't mix in under one query, if you care much about atomicity then there's this solution:

normalise your schema to,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
    userId : ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
    point : 5
}
```

Comment: creating or updating this schema document is possible in one query

Answer (score -2):

You could use a variation of the **[.forEach/.updateOne method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591042/mongodb-4-0-aggregation-addfields-not-saving-documents-after-using-todate/69429447#69429447)** I currently use in mongosh CLI to do things like that.  In the **.forEach**, you might be able to set all of your if/then conditions that you mentioned.

**Example of .forEach/.updateOne:**

```
let medications = db.medications.aggregate([
  {$match: {patient_id: {$exists: true}}}
]).toArray();

medications.forEach(med => {
  try {
    db.patients.updateOne({patient_id: med.patient_id}, 
      {$push: {medications: med}}
    )
  } catch {
    console.log("Didn't find match for patient_id.  Could not add this med to a patient.")
  }  
})
```

This may not be the most "MongoDB way" to do it, but it definitely works and gives you the freedom of javascript to do things within the **.forEach**.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is very non-idiomatic (why use an aggregation for a simple query in the first lines?). If you're going to use an aggregation, it'd be better to aggregate over the entire collection, perform your updates inline, and then `$merge` the output with the original collection. But as others have mentioned, the best solution is probably the update + aggregation pipeline syntax from MongoDB 4.2+. Also, it'd be better to use `.forEach` instead of `.toArray` on the initial query if you did it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Definitely had and still do have a lot to learn with MongoDB operations.