# MongoDB upsert array using NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I need to insert a list of elements and check if the element exists in database, if the element exists then the element will be update.

I used upsert and array:

```
    dbo.collection("Ebooks").update(arrayValues, {upsert: true, multi: true},function(err, res) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log("finish");
         db.close();
    });
```

Array eg:

```
[{_id: 10, name='Teste1'}, {_id: 11, name='Teste2'}]
```

And is returning this error:

MongoError: BSON field 'update.updates.q' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'

How I convert Array to this Object?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `arrayValues` ? can you paste here?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588342/can-mongo-upsert-array-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document. You've to iterate input array and do a two step process as mentioned in duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array

Comment: Each of the records is an element of the NodeJs array

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but looks like you don't pass query(first parameter), what data should de updated.

```
dbo.collection("Ebooks").update((), arrayValues, {upsert: true, multi: true},function(err, res) {})
```

or

```
dbo.collection("Ebooks").update((_id:someValue), arrayValues, {upsert: true, multi: true},function(err, res) {})
```