# how to insert an object to array in mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

i have an array in **mongodb**

```
  myArray [ ]
```

i want to insert an object that looks like below.

```
myArray [ myObject { key: value, key: value } ]
```

my question is how to insert an object that look like above in **mongodb**

Comment: I think your answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431240/8556874

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

You want this update query:

```
db.collection.update(
    { _id : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")},
    { $push: {"myarray": {
        key: value, key: value
    }}
)
```