# Conditionally set element of array or push new element in mongo update

Tags: mongodb

I have documents that look like this:

```json
{
    "_id": ...,
    "content": [
        {
            "language": "fr",
            "title": "Bonjour"
        },
        {
            "language": "en",
            "title": "Hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

When somebody submits a new translation (a title and a language), I would like to either:

- push the element if the langage is not present
- update the corresponding object if not

Any idea how I could achieve that with an `update` command?

I have managed to figure out if the language exists in the array and find the index but I struggle with conditionally `pushing` or `setting` based on that result.

Comment: see similar question [MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array)

Comment: there are 2 options only, 1) do 2 update queries or 2) update with aggregation pipeline, i have added a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967584/8987128) using aggregation pipeline in same question.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need.
Sorry I missed it.