# it is possible do this with a upsert?

Tags: mongodb

I want to know how to do the following if is possible with a upsert in order to avoid a lot of code:

The logic is the following,

function get two values for X and Y
Each document should have X and Y array

first insert I will create a document {[X], [Y]}
The second insert will happen only if Y value is new Y now y Z

the document now will by {[X, X], [Y, Z]}

I have the following code, but I want to know if is possible to use an upsert in order to zip the code.

```
hoo = await collection.findOne(
      {'origins': 
              {"$elemMatch": {'url': urlInput.url}}
      },
    )

    if (!hoo) {
      try{
        const result = await collection.insertOne({
            "origins": [{
              "url": urlInput.url,
              "date": urlInput.date
            }],
            "aces": [{
              "name": urlInput.name
            }]
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
        
    } else if (hoo.aces.filter(ace => {ace.name === urlInput.name}).length === 0) {
      await collection.updateOne(
        {"_id": {"$eq":hoo._id}},
        {"$push":{
          "origins": {
            "url": urlInput.url,
            "date": urlInput.date
            }
          ,
          "aces": {
            "name": urlInput.name
          }
        }
      }
      )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array)

Comment: for single query you can use update with aggregation pipeline, i have added [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967584/8987128) with that.