# NojeJs Mongoose - push array object into mongo if the data is not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arrayobject

Im very new with nodejs. I want to check in mongodb if the value is exist or not, if exist, update linkview, if does not exist i want to push an object into array. Can anyone help me on how to write a statement to check the value is exist or not in db? So this is my latest code. i have a problem, if user doesn't have yet the affiliatelink data in mongo, the log should be `item is not existed` but, im getting `item is existed`. Can anyone check my code? Please help

So this is `Admin` schema

```
{        
  "_id": "868",
  "name": "James",
  "__v": 0,
  "affiliatelink": [
    {
      "storeId": "12345",
      "storeName": "white choc",
      "linkview": 1
    },
    {
      "storeId": "67890",
      "storeName": "dark choc",
      "linkview": 2
    },
  ]
}

{        
  "_id": "135",
  "name": "Marrie",
  "__v": 0,
  "affiliatelink": []
}
```

My current code.

```
Admin.findById(adminId,{"affiliatelink.storeId":storeId}).then(admin =>{
        if(admin){
            Admin.update(
                { _id: adminId},
                {$inc: {"affiliatelink.$[elem].linkview": 1}},
                {arrayFilters: [{"elem.storeId": {$eq: storeId}}]},
                function(err){
                    console.log("item is existed")
                }
                
            )}else
            {
                let item = {
                    store: storeSlug,
                    storeId: storeId,
                    linkview: 0,
                    addtocart: 0,
                    totalpricecheckout: 0
                }

                Admin.update(
                    { _id: adminId },
                    {$push: {
                        affiliatelink: item
                            }
                    },
                    function(err, result) {
                        console.log("item is not existed")
  
            })}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array)

Comment: There is no straight way to do this in a single query, but if you want you can try update with aggregation pipeline recently i have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array/65967584#65967584) in above question.

Comment: @turivishal its working now. i change my code to something like this ` Admin.findOne({_id: adminId,"affiliatelink.storeId":storeId}).then(admin =>{`. now its working already. thanks everyone