# Update if ducument exists in array or push new Document in array

Tags: mongodb

I have a document

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    arr: [
      {
        name: "j",
        age: 2
      },
      {
        name: "k",
        age: 3
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

I want to update array embedded document's field age to 5 where `name=="j"`. If `name=="j"` not exists push new document  `{name:"j", age:5 }` to arr field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
const documents = [
        {
                "key": 1,
                arr: [
                        {
                                name: "w",
                                age: 2
                        },
                        {
                                name: "j",
                                age: 3
                        }
                ]
        },
        {
             "key": 2,
                arr: [
                        {
                                name: "w",
                                age: 2
                        },
                        {
                                name: "j",
                                age: 2
                        }
                ]    
        }

];


const updatedDocument = documents.map((document) => {

        const hasJ = document.arr.find((el) => el.name === 'j');
        let result;
        if (hasJ) {
                result = document.arr.map((el) => el.name === 'j' ? ({ ...el, age: 5 }) : el);
        } else {
                result = document.arr.concat({
                        name: 'j',
                        age: 10
                })
        }

        return {
                ...document,
                arr: result
        }
});

console.log('updatedDocument', updatedDocument);
```