# How to update an array field on mongodb by pushing it if the element is not present and if it is present update it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a IT ticketing system where every time a new comment or a note has been added to a ticket a notification needs to be send to the user who is following the ticket. Below code only inserts new ticket in list of tickets followed by the user if it is not already present, however if it is present it ignores it. What I need to do is if the ticket that has just been updated is already present, change clicked field to false. In my application's frontend, when user clicks the notification icon it will change clicked to TRUE but when a new comment is added clicked needs to be changed to FALSE so that the user gets notification that comment has been added to the same ticket. How do I go about achieving it?

```
const ReqNotificationSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  notifications: [
    {
      request: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Request" },
      clicked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },
  ],
});


if(updated){

await ReqNotificationModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            user: follower.user,
            "notifications.request": { $ne: updated._id },
          },
          {
            $push: { notifications: { request: updated._id, clicked: false } },
          },
          { new: true }
        );
}
```

Comment: It is possible to perform this kind of update with a single update operation using _Updates with Aggregation Pipeline_. Here is an example post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do it in one step , so I tried in a 2 step approach.

```
const notification = await ReqNotificationModel.findOne({
          user: follower.user,
        });
        let index = notification.notifications
          .map((obj) => obj.request.toString())
          .indexOf(updated._id.toString());

        notification.notifications[index].clicked = false;

        
        await notification.save();
 });
```