# updating mongo object on basis of website object

Tags: mongodb

**There is mongo object**

```
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3abda9ff4d600da5b0168"), 
        "regionId" : NumberInt(3526), 
        "regionName" : "So Cal", 
        "categories" : [
            "Other", 
            "Topicals", 
            "Tincture", 
            "Cannabis", 
            "Edibles", 
            "Extracts", 
            "Prerolled", 
            "Vape Cartridges"
        ]
}
```

**Website object comes like this**

```
{ "regionId" : 3526, 
        "regionName" : "So Cal", 
        "categories" : [
            "Other",
            "Seeds", 
            "Tincture", 
            "Cannabis", 
            "Edibles", 
            "Extracts", 
            "Prerolled", 
            "Vape Cartridges"
        ]
}
```

**FINAL OBJECT SHOULD BE LIKE**

```
  { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3abda9ff4d600da5b0168"), 
            "regionId" : NumberInt(3526), 
            "regionName" : "So Cal", 
            "categories" : [
                "Other",
                "Seeds",
                "Tincture", 
                "Cannabis", 
                "Edibles", 
                "Extracts", 
                "Prerolled", 
                "Vape Cartridges"
            ]
    }
```

This object comes from a website and categories elements keep on changing.
what I want to achieve is if some new element comes in categories then it should be inserted in my mongo and if some element is not there in the website and there in my mongo, it should be deleted from my mongo object.

**$addToSet will only solve the problem if some new element is added but what in case of delete ?**

(I'm an absolute beginner) in mongo please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can mongo upsert array data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588342/can-mongo-upsert-array-data)

Comment: $addToSet will only solve the problem if some new element is added but what in case of delete  @AyushGupta

Comment: do you mean, if an array item coming from the website is not in the categories array in mongo, you want to insert it and if it is not in the array item but in mongo you want to remove the value?

Comment: EXACTLY i want this @0.sh

Comment: do value from the website is extacly like the document represented in your question, or it comes as an array?

Comment: value from website comes like 

{ "regionId" : 3526, 
        "regionName" : "So Cal", 
        "categories" : [
            "Other",
            "Seeds", 
            "Tincture", 
            "Cannabis", 
            "Edibles", 
            "Extracts", 
            "Prerolled", 
            "Vape Cartridges"
        ]
}

@0.sh

Comment: represent it in your question

Comment: represented @0.sh

Answer (score 0):

the `update` command can solve this

```
// value coming from website
 var obj = { 
        "regionId" : 3526, 
        "regionName" : "So Cal", 
         "categories" : [
            "Other",
            "Seeds", 
            "Tincture", 
            "Cannabis", 
            "Edibles", 
            "Extracts", 
            "Prerolled", 
            "Vape Cartridges"
        ]
 }

> db.drugs.insert(obj);
> db.drugs.find({regionId: obj.regionId}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3ba064a7f0d521aa4dacb"),
    "regionId" : 3526,
    "regionName" : "So Cal",
    "categories" : [
        "Other",
        "Seeds",
        "Tincture",
        "Cannabis",
        "Edibles",
        "Extracts",
        "Prerolled",
        "Vape Cartridges"
    ]
}

// assuming the category changes
// push adds an element to categories
> obj.categories.push("concain");
> db.drugs.update( { regionId: obj.regionId }, obj ); 
> db.drugs.find({regionId: obj.regionId}).pretty()
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3ba064a7f0d521aa4dacb"),
   "regionId" : 3526,
   "regionName" : "So Cal",
   "categories" : [
      "Other",
      "Seeds",
      "Tincture",
      "Cannabis",
      "Edibles",
      "Extracts",
      "Prerolled",
      "Vape Cartridges",
      "hello"
  ]
}

// remove hello from the categories
> obj.categories.pop();
> db.drug.update( { regionId: obj.regionId }, obj );
> db.drugs.find({regionId: obj.regionId}).pretty();
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3ba064a7f0d521aa4dacb"),
  "regionId" : 3526,
  "regionName" : "So Cal",
  "categories" : [
     "Other",
     "Seeds",
     "Tincture",
     "Cannabis",
     "Edibles",
     "Extracts",
     "Prerolled",
     "Vape Cartridges"
  ]
}
```